# I have a vector whose elements contain multiple numbers. How do I sum numbers inside each element and create a new vector?

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector of class `'factor'` like:

```
vec <-c("1,1,1,1,1,2","2,1,2","3,3,4")
```

And I want to get another vector like this:

```
sumvec <- c(7, 5, 10)
```

How do I do this? I am using R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
> sapply(strsplit(as.character(vec), ","), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
[1]  7  5 10
```

The basic idea is to split the character vector, extract the numeric values, and calculate the sum. `strsplit` doesn't work on factors, so if you actually have factors, you'll need to convert them to characters first. Similarly, `sum` won't work on the resulting characters, so you need to convert that to numeric first.